# How can we add Gif to the background for three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, background

```js
function createScene() {
  cubeSize = 200;
  fieldDepth = 50;
  fieldWidth = 200;
  fieldHeight = 200;
  initObstacles = _ => _;
  // set the scene size
  var WIDTH = 1000;
  var HEIGHT = 500;

  // set camera attributes
  var VIEW_ANGLE = 40,
    ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT,
    NEAR = 0.1,
    FAR = 1000;

  // --------------create a WebGL renderer, camera and a scene------------------


  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
  });
  // start the renderer
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(500, 1.25, 0.1, 1000);

  // ----------Add the camera to the scene----------
  scene.add(camera);

  // Set a default position for the camera
  camera.position.z = 225;


  // Attach the render-supplied DOM element to the gameCanvas
  var c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  c.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // Make a cube with Lambert material
  // ---------------------------------
  // Lower fragments can increase performance
  var cubeWidth = cubeSize,
    cubeHeight = cubeSize,
    cubeDepth = 10,
    cubeQuality = 1;
  // create the cube's material
  var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xb22222
  });
  //---------create a cube with sphere geometry and the meterial--------------


  cube = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(
      cubeWidth,
      cubeHeight,
      cubeDepth,
      cubeQuality,
      cubeQuality,
      cubeQuality
    ),
    cubeMaterial);

  // lift the cube to half of the playing space height
  cube.position.z = fieldDepth / 2;
  // set the cube x position in the left of the play field
  cube.position.x = -fieldWidth / 3;

  // add the cube to the scene
  scene.add(cube);

  // Make sky background plane
  // sky plane vars

  var planeWidth = fieldWidth,
    planeHeight = fieldHeight,
    planeQuality = 5;
  // create plane's material
  var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({

    color: 0xff0000

  });
  //----------create the playing surface plane--------


  var plane = new THREE.Mesh(
    // changed PlaneGeometry to PlaneBufferGeometry for lower memory footprint
    new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(
      planeWidth,
      planeHeight,
      planeQuality,

    ),
    planeMaterial);


  scene.add(plane);

  // Obstacles
  initObstacles();

  //---------------Lights------------


  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
  directionalLight.position.set(0, 0, 100);
  directionalLight.rotation.x = 90 * Math.PI / 180;
  scene.add(directionalLight);
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
createScene();
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="gameCanvas"></div>
```

Comment: How have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

add a background to your canvas

```
canvas {
  background-image: url("https://greggman.com/images/godzilla.gif");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```js
function createScene() {
  cubeSize = 200;
  fieldDepth = 50;
  fieldWidth = 200;
  fieldHeight = 200;
  initObstacles = _ => _;
  // set the scene size
  var WIDTH = 1000;
  var HEIGHT = 500;

  // set camera attributes
  var VIEW_ANGLE = 40,
    ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT,
    NEAR = 0.1,
    FAR = 1000;

  // --------------create a WebGL renderer, camera and a scene------------------


  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
  });
  // start the renderer
  renderer.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(500, 1.25, 0.1, 1000);

  // ----------Add the camera to the scene----------
  scene.add(camera);

  // Set a default position for the camera
  camera.position.z = 225;


  // Attach the render-supplied DOM element to the gameCanvas
  var c = document.getElementById("gameCanvas");
  c.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // Make a cube with Lambert material
  // ---------------------------------
  // Lower fragments can increase performance
  var cubeWidth = cubeSize,
    cubeHeight = cubeSize,
    cubeDepth = 10,
    cubeQuality = 1;
  // create the cube's material
  var cubeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xb22222
  });
  //---------create a cube with sphere geometry and the meterial--------------


  cube = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(
      cubeWidth,
      cubeHeight,
      cubeDepth,
      cubeQuality,
      cubeQuality,
      cubeQuality
    ),
    cubeMaterial);

  // lift the cube to half of the playing space height
  cube.position.z = fieldDepth / 2;
  // set the cube x position in the left of the play field
  cube.position.x = -fieldWidth / 3;

  // add the cube to the scene
  scene.add(cube);

  // Make sky background plane
  // sky plane vars

  var planeWidth = fieldWidth,
    planeHeight = fieldHeight,
    planeQuality = 5;
  // create plane's material
  var planeMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({

    color: 0xff0000

  });
  //----------create the playing surface plane--------


  var plane = new THREE.Mesh(
    // changed PlaneGeometry to PlaneBufferGeometry for lower memory footprint
    new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(
      planeWidth,
      planeHeight,
      planeQuality,

    ),
    planeMaterial);


  scene.add(plane);

  // Obstacles
  initObstacles();

  //---------------Lights------------


  var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1);
  directionalLight.position.set(0, 0, 100);
  directionalLight.rotation.x = 90 * Math.PI / 180;
  scene.add(directionalLight);
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
createScene();
```

```css
canvas {
  background-image: url("https://greggman.com/images/godzilla.gif");
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r122/build/three.min.js"></script>
<div id="gameCanvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this was very useful